# How to Turn a Button to an Image in Jquery?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to turn an image with text over it into a button. If I use data-role="button", the whole arrangement of the image and the text over it gets all messed up. Any ideas on how to do that and maintain the arrangement as it is? Also, how can I make the text background fit the image perfectly?

```css
img {
    width: 50 px;
    height: 50 px;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    text - align: center;
    color: white;
}
.centered {
    font - size: 30 px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50 % ;
    left: 50 % ;
    transform: translate(-50 % , -50 % );
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    line - height: 200 px;
    width: 50 px;
    height: 50 px;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature-wrapper" class="ui-block-d" data-role="button">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Birnbaum_am_Lerchenberg_retouched.jpg/310px-Birnbaum_am_Lerchenberg_retouched.jpg" />
        <div class="centered">Tree</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/tree------------------->
```

Comment: Where did you put `data-role="button"`?

Comment: Just put the click event on the image, and using CSS change the  mousepointer to appear as a link

Comment: Or you could also wrap your image with a button. Or you could just use a button and set the background property of it as the image

Answer (score 1):

**You can use your image as button like this -**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature-wrapper" class=ui-block-d>
  <div class="container">
    <img onclick="alert('Your function');" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Birnbaum_am_Lerchenberg_retouched.jpg/310px-Birnbaum_am_Lerchenberg_retouched.jpg" alt="Tree"/>
    <div class="centered">Tree</div>
  </div>
</div>
```